# Orocrm aplication from 1.10 to 2.4.0 to 3.1.20

Tags: orocrm

currently we are trying to upgrade OroCRM 1.10 application to OroCRM 2.4 application ( oro/crm : 2.4.0 and oro/platform : 2.4.0).

If upgrage till 2.4 will be succesfull,  is it possible to upgrade to version orocrm application 3.1.20 (oro/crm : 3.1.17 and oro/platform : 3.1.20), or before version 3 upgrade we should upgrade till version till 2.6.*?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Direct migration could work.

However, officially Oro supports migration only between LTS releases (latest 1.12, latest 2.6, latest 3.1, latest 4.1).

So, it is recommended to upgrade to 2.6, then to 3.1 and at the end to the current long term support release - 4.1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer, but i have question you say that latest version for version 1 is 1.12 but i can not find it, latest version for crm-application is 1.10.31, for (crm 1.10.26) and platform 1.10.31, where is can find version 1.12? Maybe you mean 1.12.34 for OroCRM Enterprise Edition? In our project we do not use EE OroCrm.

Is it true, that latest version 3 platform (3.1.20) platform support php 7.2 and 7.3

Comment: > Is it true, that the latest version 3 platform (3.1.20) platform supports PHP 7.2 and 7.3. 
Yes, see https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/3.1.20/composer.json#L13

Comment: Thanks Andrey, for your response